# fresh installation of IIS 7.5 ignores <system.web> in my web.config

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, web.config

I have deployed a web application as usual, but on already installed and running Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS 7.5.

On all machines until now the application works fine, but here an entire `<system.web>` section from my `web.config` is not used at all. We use it to specify some settings, like `sessionState cookieless="true"`, enable Role Manager etc (debug mode is also disabled if I try to look around).

I have also looked in applicationHost.config on the machine, but there is no mention of overrideMode="Deny" for this section.

It seems to me that something is disabling my system.web section, but it's a fresh installation of IIS. Is it possible that there is some kind of company-wide policy coming from somewhere, but I really have no idea on what to try next.

Answer (score 0):

Might seem like a basic question, but is ASP.NET installed?  Do basic ASP.NET pages work, what you are describing doesn't seem like an IIS issue as much as configuration.